# что исправить в программе?

Tags: c++, массивы, visual-c++

```
 #include <iostream.>
 #include <iomanip.>
 using namespace std;


 void input(float[4][5], char);
 void output(float[4][5], char *);
 void output(float[4], char *);
 void preobr(float[4], float[4][5]);

void main()
{

float F[4][5], A[4][5], X[4], V[4];

input(F, 'F');
input(A, 'A');
preobr(X, F);
preobr(V, A);
output(F, "Исходный массив F:\n");
output(X, "Преобразованный массив X:\n");
output(A, "Исходный массив A:\n");
output(V, "Преобразованный массив V:\n");
}

void input(float x[4][5], char name)
{
int i, j;
cout << "Вводим массив " << name << endl;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
    {
        cout << " Введите элемент массива " << name << "[" << i << "][" << j 
   << "]=";
        cin >> x[i][j];
    }
 }

 void output(float x[4][5], char * zag)
{
int i, j;
cout << endl << endl << zag << endl;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
        cout << setw(5) << x[i][j];
}
}

{
int i;
cout << endl << endl << zag << endl;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
    cout << setw(5) << x[i];
cout << endl;
 }
 void preobr(float m[4], float n[4][5])
 {
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
    m[i] = 0;
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
        if ((n[i][j]<0) && (n[i][j]>m[i] || m[i] == 0)) m[i] = n[i][j];

}
 }
```

в строках

```
output(F, "Исходный массив F:\n");
output(X, "Преобразованный массив X:\n");
output(A, "Исходный массив A:\n");
output(V, "Преобразованный массив V:\n");
```

выдает ошибки "отсутствуют экземпляры перегруженная функция "output" ,соответствующие списку аргументов.
Помогите,пожалуйста,что нужно исправить?

Comment: Для начала нужно исправить заголовок вопроса. По нему должна быть понятна проблема, задача.

Answer (score 0):

Начнем с того, что у вас вот тут - см. комментарий (вы не пробовали хотя бы из уважения к другим иногда исходники форматировать?) -

```
 void output(float x[4][5], char * zag)
{
int i, j;
cout << endl << endl << zag << endl;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j<5; j++)
        cout << setw(5) << x[i][j];
}
}
///// <- Вот тут
{
int i;
cout << endl << endl << zag << endl;
for (i = 0; i<4; i++)
    cout << setw(5) << x[i];
cout << endl;
 }
```

Вообще нет заголовка функции. Оно же не компилируемо...

Как только вы помещаете туда

```
void output(float x[4], char * zag)
```

так все сразу компилируется.

Работает ли - не знаю, не проверял. Но компилируется :)